# Django ForeignKey: using in reverse order. What form element is shown

Tags: django

I have a student project relationship. One student can be assigned to only one project. A project can have multiple students

The following is my student and Project model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How to get create the relationship in this case

Comment: It's not clear what "how to get create the relationship" means - please clarify your question. If you're asking how to link a student to a project, then you're looking for a ForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day!

add following line:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # This

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

This way a student can have only one project, project can have many students.